# Web API 2.0 Using MySQL Identity Provider, AuthContext?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I am attempting to setup token authentication using ASP.NET Identity in a WebAPI 2 with a MySQL Backend using this tutorial.

http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Unfortunately, this example uses Entity Framework and I am attempting to substitute it where ever I can (if it is even possible) with MySQL.

I have so far come to step 5, creating an authentication repository. This is the example given:

```
public class AuthRepository : IDisposable
{
    private AuthContext _ctx;

    private UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public AuthRepository()
    {
        _ctx = new AuthContext();
        _userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(_ctx));
    }

    public async Task<IdentityResult> RegisterUser(UserModel userModel)
    {
        IdentityUser user = new IdentityUser
        {
            UserName = userModel.UserName
        };

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, userModel.Password);

        return result;
    }

    public async Task<IdentityUser> FindUser(string userName, string password)
    {
        IdentityUser user = await _userManager.FindAsync(userName, password);

        return user;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _ctx.Dispose();
        _userManager.Dispose();

    }
}
```

I substituted UserManager for MySQLUserManager, but I cannot make an AuthContext.
Does anybody know what I must reference, or replace.

Maybe I do not even need to reference it, as in my IdentityConfig.cs file I only have:

```
        //Old entity framework stuff
        //var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));

        //shiny new mysql stuff
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new MySqlUserStore<ApplicationUser>());
```

(based off this tutorial http://blog.developers.ba/asp-net-identity-2-1-for-mysql/)

If I need an application user, should I pass it somehow?

**I re-read the tutorial and came across this snippet, it appears to be a connection string of some sort.**

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="AuthContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=AngularJSAuth;Integrated Security=SSPI;"   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

What could or should I replace it with?

Comment: Entity Framework is an ORM, not a database. It works with many different databases. If you want to use a different database you should change the connection string, *NOT* the ORM. You can find out how to use MySQL with EF in MySQL's site, in the [EF 6 Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html) chapter

Comment: I've managed to make it work with a friend, replacing EF with MySQL (there was a mistake in the tutorial regarding startup code order and such, he'll post an order)

Comment: He'll post an answer*

Comment: As I said, EF isn't specific to SQL Server, it also works with MySQL. *Why* are you rewriting all this code instead of simply changing the connection string?